# Fallo al iniciar sesión con usuario de base de datos

Tags: php, mysql, poo, login, session

Cuando yo en mi login, intento acceder a mi `index.php`, siempre me dice: "Tu nombre de usuario o clave son incorrectos", que está en el `controller_login.php`. Me he asegurado, que mi usuario está creado correctamente en la base de datos. Por ejemplo, el usuario "a" con contraseña "a", no accede mediante login al `index.php`("Hola, accediendo") No se que puede ocurrir y no encuentro solución.

**login.php:**

```
<?php
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['usuario']);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="estilos/login.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
            <h2>Login</h2>
        <form class="w3-container" action="controller_login.php" method="post"> <!---importante; falla controller_login--->
            <p>
                <input class="w3-input w3-border" type="text" name="usuario" placeholder="Usuario">
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="w3-input w3-border" type="password" name="pas" placeholder="Contraseña">
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="hidden" name="acceder" value="Acceder">
                <button class="w3-btn w3-green">Acceder</button>
            </p>
            <p>Si aún no tienes cuenta ve al siguiente link<a href="registro.php"> Registrarse</a></p>
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

**controller_login.php:**

```
    //inicio de sesion
    session_start();

    $usuario=new Usuario();
    $crud=new CrudUsuario();
    //verifica si la variable registrarse está definida
    //se da que está definicda cuando el usuario se loguea, ya que la envía en la petición
    if (isset($_POST['registrarse'])) {
                $usuario->setNombre($_POST['nombre']);
        $usuario->setUsuario($_POST['usuario']); 
        $usuario->setPass($_POST['pas']);
                /*terminar codigo y foto_perfil?-> no realmente necesario*/
                $usuario->setPais($_POST['pais']);
                $usuario->setProfesion($_POST['profe']);
                $usuario->setEdad($_POST['edad']);

        if ($crud->buscarUsuario($_POST['usuario'])) {
            $crud->insertar($usuario);
            header('Location: login.php');
        }else{
            header('Location: error.php?mensaje=El nombre de usuario ya existe');
        }       

    }elseif (isset($_POST['acceder'])) { //verifica si la variable entrar está definida
        $usuario=$crud->obtenerUsuario($_POST['usuario'],$_POST['pas']);
        // si el id del objeto retornado no es null, quiere decir que encontro un registro en la base
        if ($usuario->getUsuario()!=NULL) {
            $_SESSION['usuario']=$usuario; //si el usuario se encuentra, crea la sesión de usuario
            header('Location: index.php'); //envia a la página que simula la cuenta
        }else{
            header('Location: error.php?mensaje=Tu nombre de usuario o clave son incorrectos'); // cuando los datos son incorrectos envia a la página de error
        }
    }elseif(isset($_POST['salir'])){ // cuando presiona el botòn salir
        header('Location: login.php');
        unset($_SESSION['usuario']); //destruye la sesión
    }
?>
```

**crud_usuario.php:**

```
<?php 
    require_once('conexion.php');
    require_once('usuario.php');

    class CrudUsuario{

        public function __construct(){}

        //inserta los datos del usuario
        public function insertar($usuario){ /*funciona*/
            $db=DB::conectar();
            $insert=$db->prepare('INSERT INTO USUARIOS (nombre, usuario, pass, pais, profesion, edad) VALUES(:nombre, :usuario, :pass, :pais, :profesion, :edad)');
            $insert->bindValue('nombre',$usuario->getNombre());
                        $insert->bindValue('usuario',$usuario->getUsuario());
            //encripta la clave
            $pass=password_hash($usuario->getPass(),PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
            $insert->bindValue('pass',$pass);
                        $insert->bindValue('pais',$usuario->getPais());
                        $insert->bindValue('profesion',$usuario->getProfesion());
                        $insert->bindValue('edad',$usuario->getEdad());
            $insert->execute();
        }

        //obtiene el usuario para el login
        public function obtenerUsuario($nombre, $clave){ /*revisar*/
            $db=Db::conectar();
            $select=$db->prepare('SELECT * FROM USUARIOS WHERE usuario=:usuario AND pass=:pass');//AND pass=pass
            $select->bindValue('usuario',$nombre);
                        $select->bindValue('pass',$clave);
            $select->execute();
            $registro=$select->fetch();
            $usuario=new Usuario();
            //verifica si la clave es conrrecta
            if (password_verify($clave, $registro['pass'])) { 
                //si es correcta, asigna los valores que trae desde la base de datos
                /*$usuario->setCodusua($registro['CodUsua']);*/
                                $usuario->setNombre($registro['nombre']);
                $usuario->setUsuario($registro['usuario']);
                $usuario->setPass($registro['pass']); /*pass en mi bd*/
            }           
            return $usuario;
        }

        //busca el nombre del usuario si existe
        public function buscarUsuario($nombre){ /*revisar*/
            $db=Db::conectar();
            $select=$db->prepare('SELECT * FROM USUARIOS WHERE nombre=:nombre');
            $select->bindValue('nombre',$nombre);
            $select->execute();
            $registro=$select->fetch();
            if($registro['nombre']!=NULL){ /*nombre?*/
                $usado=False;
            }else{
                $usado=True;
            }   
            return $usado;
        }
    }
?>
```

**index.php:**

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['usuario'])){
    header('Location: login.php');
}

?>

<html>
<body>    
<h1>Hola, accediendo</h1>
<form class="w3-container" action="controller_login.php" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="salir" value="salir">
            <button class="w3-btn w3-green">Salir</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**error.php:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Error al ingresar</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, intial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="w3-container w3-black w3-center">
                <h1>RED SOCIAL</h1>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div class="w3-container w3-red">
            <h1><?php echo $_GET['mensaje'];?></h1>
            <a href="login.php">Volver a ingresar</a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Clase Usuario.php**:

```
<?php

class Usuario {
    private $codusua;
    private $nombre;
    private $usuario;
    private $pass;
    private $pais;
    private $profesion;
    private $edad;
    private $foto_perfil;

    function getCodusua() {
        return $this->codusua;
    }

    function getNombre() {
        return $this->nombre;
    }

    function getUsuario() {
        return $this->usuario;
    }

    function getPass() {
        return $this->pass;
    }

    function getPais() {
        return $this->pais;
    }

    function getProfesion() {
        return $this->profesion;
    }

    function getEdad() {
        return $this->edad;
    }

    function getFoto_perfil() {
        return $this->foto_perfil;
    }

    function setCodusua($codusua) {
        $this->codusua = $codusua;
    }

    function setNombre($nombre) {
        $this->nombre = $nombre;
    }

    function setUsuario($usuario) {
        $this->usuario = $usuario;
    }

    function setPass($pass) {
        $this->pass = $pass;
    }

    function setPais($pais) {
        $this->pais = $pais;
    }

    function setProfesion($profesion) {
        $this->profesion = $profesion;
    }

    function setEdad($edad) {
        $this->edad = $edad;
    }

    function setFoto_perfil($foto_perfil) {
        $this->foto_perfil = $foto_perfil;
    }
}
```

Comment: El problema esta en el `$db->prepare` no le debes de pasar el pass solo el nombre de usuario, por que si comparas el pass en texto plano con el pass encriptado de la bd no te va a coincidir, esta debes hacerlo con `password_verify` como tienes debajo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dado que guardas la conraseña encriptada, al buscar el usuario en la base de datos no debes hacerlo por la conraseña, ya que no van a coincidir la pass en texto plano con la pass encriptada debes hacerlo solo por el usuario, luego validar la pass. También le añadiria un `LIMIT 1` al SQL ya que el usuario debe ser único y no hay necesidad de seguir escaneando la tabla si ya se encontró un registro:

```
    public function obtenerUsuario($nombre, $clave){
        $db = Db::conectar();
        $usuario = new Usuario();

        // Ajustamos el SQL
        $select = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM USUARIOS WHERE usuario=:usuario LIMIT 1');
        $select->bindValue('usuario', $nombre);
        // Esto sobra
        // $select->bindValue('pass',$clave);
        $select->execute();
        $registro = $select->fetch();

        // aquí es donde verificas la pass no en el SQL
        if (password_verify($clave, $registro['pass'])) { 
            //si es correcta, asigna los valores que trae desde la base de datos
            /*$usuario->setCodusua($registro['CodUsua']);*/
            $usuario->setNombre($registro['nombre']);
            $usuario->setUsuario($registro['usuario']);
            $usuario->setPass($registro['pass']); /*pass en mi bd*/
        }           
        return $usuario;
    }
```

También veo que en algunos lados utilizas el campo `usuario=:usuario` y en otros `nombre=:nombre` no se si tienes los 2 campos pero deberias de elegir cual de ellos se utilizará para iniciar sesion y debería ser un campo único si no lo es ya.

Comment: Realmente es usuario=:usuario en todos los casos, ya que la búsqueda es por el usuario y no el nombre. Tienes razón. No obstante, he modificado el código con sus correcciones y sigue entrando por el else del 
 " header('Location: error.php?mensaje=Tu nombre de usuario o clave son incorrectos'); "